# How to Read the message Body in a HTTP POST in Netty (version >= 4.x)

Tags: http, netty, nio

In my server handler;
- channelRead() always gets the msg as HTTPRequest and there I cannot find any place to get the POST request payload.

- Then I tried following in my handler to check if it works. The decoder has 0 elements.

HttpPostRequestDecoder decoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(new DefaultHttpDataFactory(false), request);

In my server pipeline I have HttpServerCodec and a custom handler only.

Comment: Could you please add the full configuration of your pipeline?

Comment: @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new MyServerHandler());
    }

Answer (score 9):

It's likely that your HTTP request is chunked. You should try to add an `io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator` to your pipeline, just after the codecs. It will give a FullHttpRequest to your handler.

```
 ChannelPipeline p = ...;
 ...
 p.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
 p.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
 p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
 ...
 p.addLast("handler", new MyServerHandler());
```

Alternatively, you could check [this example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java) where `HttpRequest` and `HttpContent` are handled separately.

Answer (score 7):

As Leo Gomes mentioned, HTTP Request maybe chunked. so add HttpObjectAggregator before your own handler in pipeline.
if HTTP POST request body is Simple Json String. You can parse it in your own handler like this:

```java
    private String parseJosnRequest(FullHttpRequest request){
        ByteBuf jsonBuf = request.content();
        String jsonStr = jsonBuf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        return jsonStr;
    }
```